# Laravel 5.7 checking code in tinker, but i have a problem while getting values from model class?

Tags: laravel-5.7

my question is totaly different from that question, in that question they are telling about php versions and all, that question didn't solved my issue, thats why I haved asked my own question. @Álvaro González

I have created 4 models with this command

```
php artisan make:model class
php artisan make:model student
php artisan make:model subject
php artisan make:model user
```

I have created migrations and everything, but the problem is when I test my models in `php artisan tinker` with this command `App\student::all();` then `subject` `user` and `student` models are working and shows me data but `App\class::all();` is not working and showing me this error

PHP Parse error, Unexpected T_CLASS, Expecting T_STRING

I have also migration for class and also data is present in class table in database, but I don't know why it's not working, Any help would be appreciated Thanks

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword, rename it to something else. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Comment: I was thinking that as i uploaded question, let me try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This model is invalid:

```
class class extends Model
{
  //
}
```

Comment: OP found that out already, that's why the question exists. A (short) explanation on why it is invalid would be nice and helpful.

Comment: Boom, just saw that! I thought the visual aid of `class class` told the story... way to knock my peep in the ground yo.